# Having an issue with link lists in c

Tags: c, list

I am having problems with some code I have to add the option to input a person into my structure link list. I can add the person to the first node with an integer for an identifier but then when I come to add another it only asks for the integer not for the other details. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"     /* conatins structure definition */

/*  Function Prototypes 
    Note that variable names have been removed as they are 
    not actually required - they are optional
*/
int fnTotalList(struct listnode *);
struct listnode *fnAddItem(struct listnode *, int);
void fnPrintList(struct listnode *);
int fnMenu(void);
struct listnode *fnRemoveEndItem(struct listnode *, int *);
struct listnode *fnRemoveStartItem(struct listnode *, int *);
void fnSearchList(struct listnode *, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     struct listnode *ptrHead = NULL;
     struct listnode *ptrTemp = NULL;
     int nChoice = 0;
     int nRun = 1;
     int nItem = 0;

     while(nRun)
     {
         nChoice = fnMenu();

         switch(nChoice)
         {
             case 1:    /* Add an item */
                            printf("Please enter an integer : ");
                            scanf("%d", &nItem);
                            ptrHead = fnAddItem(ptrHead,nItem);
                            break;

              case 2:   /* Print the list */
                            fnPrintList(ptrHead);
                            printf("The list total is %d\n", fnTotalList(ptrHead));
                            break;

              case 3:   /* Remove an end item */
                            ptrHead = fnRemoveEndItem(ptrHead, &nItem);
                            if(nItem == -9999)
                                printf("Nothing to remove - empty list\n\n");
                            else
                                printf("The removed value is %d\n\n", nItem);
                            break;

              case 4:   /* Remove a start item */
                            ptrHead = fnRemoveStartItem(ptrHead, &nItem);
                            if(nItem == -9999)
                                printf("Nothing to remove - empty list\n\n");
                            else
                                printf("The removed value is %d\n\n", nItem);
                            break;

              case 5:   /* Search the list */
                            printf("Please enter the search value : ");
                            scanf("%d", &nItem);
                            fnSearchList(ptrHead, nItem);
                            break;

              case 6:   /* Exit program */
                            nRun = 0;   /* set to zero to stop the while loop */
                            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

struct listnode *fnAddItem(struct listnode *ptrH, int nNumber)
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = NULL;

    if(ptrH == NULL)
    {
        /* Special case - list empty */
        ptrH = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        if(ptrH == NULL)
        {
            printf("Adding to empty list - malloc has failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* malloc has worked - set values */
        (*ptrH).nVal = nNumber;
        printf("Please Enter First , Second & Last Name : ");
        scanf("%s %s %s",(*ptrH).arcFirstName,(*ptrH).arcMiddleName,(*ptrH).arcLastName);
        printf("Please Enter Sex M or F : ");
        scanf("%s", (*ptrH).cSex);
        printf("DOB - DDMMYYYY\n");
        scanf("%i %i %i", &nD, &nM, &nY);
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nDay=nD;
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nMonth=nM;
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nYear=nY;
        ptrH->ptrNext = NULL;       /* This is important as it signals
                                                the last node within the list */
    }
    else
    {
        /* There are items already in the list
            need to locate the end - use a while loop
            to step through looking for ptrNext to
            equal NULL */

        ptrTemp = ptrH; /* Use a temp pointer */
        while(ptrTemp->ptrNext != NULL)
        {
            /* As ptrNext has a value there is a node
                hanging off it */
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }
        /* ptrTemp is now pointing at the last node
            within the list
            Now, create a new node that "hangs off"
            ptrNext within this last node  */

            ptrTemp->ptrNext = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
            if(ptrTemp->ptrNext == NULL)
            {
                printf("Adding to end of list - malloc has failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            ptrTemp->ptrNext->nVal = nNumber;
            ptrTemp->ptrNext->ptrNext = NULL;
    }

    return ptrH;    /* This is really only needed when adding the first item
                            to the list - but have to do it in all cases to avoid
                            error messages */
}

int fnMenu(void)
{
     int nChoice;

     printf("Choices menu\n\n");
     printf("1.\tAdd an item\n");
     printf("2.\tPrint list\n");
     printf("3.\tRemove an end item\n");
     printf("4.\tRemove a start item\n");
     printf("5.\tSearch for a value\n");
     printf("6.\tQuit\n\n");
     printf("Please enter a choice :");
     scanf("%d", &nChoice);

     return nChoice;
}

void fnPrintList(struct listnode *ptrH)
{
    if(!ptrH)
    {
        printf("\n\n\tEmpty list\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptrH)
        {
            printf("%d\n", ptrH->nVal);
            ptrH = ptrH->ptrNext;
        }
        printf("\nEnd of list\n\n");
    }

}

struct listnode *fnRemoveEndItem(struct listnode *ptrH, int *ptrNum)
{
    /*  There are two special cases ...
        1. When the list is empty
        2. When there is only one node within the list
    */
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = NULL;

    if(!ptrH)
    {
        /* The list is empty */
        *ptrNum = -9999;        /* A value to signal empty list */
    }
    else if(!ptrH->ptrNext)
    {
        /*  There is only one node in the list
            as ptrNext within the first node
            is NULL
        */
        *ptrNum = ptrH->nVal; 
        free(ptrH);             /*  This releases the memory allocated
                                    by malloc() back to the heap */

        ptrH = NULL;            /*  As this was the last item to remove
                                    need to return NULL so that ptrHead
                                    is set to NULL */
    }
    else
    {
        /*  There are more than one nodes in the list,
            need to step through to find the last but
            one node
        */
        ptrTemp = ptrH;
        while(ptrTemp->ptrNext->ptrNext)
        {
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }

        /*  ptrTemp is now pointing to the last but
            one node so can delete the last one
        */
        *ptrNum = ptrTemp->ptrNext->nVal;
        free(ptrTemp->ptrNext);
        ptrTemp->ptrNext = NULL;    /* Set to NULL as this is 
                                       now the last node
                                    */
    }

    return ptrH;
}


struct listnode *fnRemoveStartItem(struct listnode *ptrH, int *ptrNum)
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = NULL;

    if(!ptrH)
    {
        /*  Empty list */
        *ptrNum = -9999;
        return ptrH;
    }
    else
    {
        ptrTemp = ptrH->ptrNext;
        *ptrNum = ptrH->nVal;
        free(ptrH);
        return ptrTemp;
    }
}


void fnSearchList(struct listnode *ptrH, int nSearchVal)
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = ptrH;
    int nCount = 0;

    if(!ptrH)
    {
        /* Empty List */
        printf("\n\nEmpty List \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptrTemp->ptrNext)
        {
            if(ptrTemp->nVal == nSearchVal)
            {
                printf("The value %d has been located\n", ptrTemp->nVal);
                nCount++;
            }
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }

        if(!nCount)
            printf("\t\tValue not found within the list\n");
        else
            printf("\t\tA total of %d were found\n", nCount);
    }   
    printf("The list totals %d\n", fnTotalList(ptrH));
}

int fnTotalList(struct listnode *ptrH)
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = ptrH;
    int nTotal = 0;

    if(ptrTemp)
    {
        while(ptrTemp)
        {
            nTotal += ptrTemp->nVal;
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }
    }

    return nTotal;
}
```

Comment: Wall of code - use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `fnAddItem`, there are two cases, one is when the pointer is `NULL`, that is List Empty and you are adding the first node correctly.

Another one is when there is already some node, you are traversing to the last and adding one node there, but did not ask for input. Thats why for 2nd node onwards you don't have other details.

After you `malloc` in the `else` part, you have to take input as you did in the `if` part.

```
struct listnode *fnAddItem(struct listnode *ptrH, int nNumber)
{
    struct listnode *ptrTemp = NULL;

    if(ptrH == NULL)
    {
        /* Special case - list empty */
        ptrH = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
        if(ptrH == NULL)
        {
            printf("Adding to empty list - malloc has failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* malloc has worked - set values */
        (*ptrH).nVal = nNumber;
        printf("Please Enter First , Second & Last Name : ");
        scanf("%s %s %s",(*ptrH).arcFirstName,(*ptrH).arcMiddleName,(*ptrH).arcLastName);
        printf("Please Enter Sex M or F : ");
        scanf("%s", (*ptrH).cSex);
        printf("DOB - DDMMYYYY\n");
        scanf("%i %i %i", &nD, &nM, &nY);
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nDay=nD;
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nMonth=nM;
        (*ptrH).strDOB.nYear=nY;
        ptrH->ptrNext = NULL;       /* This is important as it signals
                                                the last node within the list */
    }
    else
    {
        /* There are items already in the list
            need to locate the end - use a while loop
            to step through looking for ptrNext to
            equal NULL */

        ptrTemp = ptrH; /* Use a temp pointer */
        while(ptrTemp->ptrNext != NULL)
        {
            /* As ptrNext has a value there is a node
                hanging off it */
            ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrNext;
        }
        /* ptrTemp is now pointing at the last node
            within the list
            Now, create a new node that "hangs off"
            ptrNext within this last node  */

            ptrTemp->ptrNext = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
            if(ptrTemp->ptrNext == NULL)
            {
                printf("Adding to end of list - malloc has failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            /* malloc has worked - set values */
        ptrTemp->ptrNext->nVal = nNumber;
        printf("Please Enter First , Second & Last Name : ");
        scanf("%s %s %s",ptrTemp->ptrNext->arcFirstName,ptrTemp->ptrNext->arcMiddleName,ptrTemp->ptrNext->arcLastName);
        printf("Please Enter Sex M or F : ");
        scanf("%s", ptrTemp->ptrNext->cSex);
        printf("DOB - DDMMYYYY\n");
        scanf("%i %i %i", &nD, &nM, &nY);
        ptrTemp->ptrNext->strDOB.nDay=nD;
        ptrTemp->ptrNext->strDOB.nMonth=nM;
        ptrTemp->ptrNext->strDOB.nYear=nY;
        ptrTemp->ptrNext->ptrNext = NULL;       /* This is important as it signals
                                                the last node within the list */  
    }

    return ptrH;    /* This is really only needed when adding the first item
                            to the list - but have to do it in all cases to avoid
                            error messages */
}
```

It is a bad design though, you should `malloc` once, take the inputs and fill the structure and then add it in appropriate place to the list. In that way you can omit a huge part of redundant code in the function.